# notifyItemChanged(int position) updates multiple items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I Am using RecyclerView for displaying a list of items, and I need to update state for single item by position. I am updating my item in list then call [notifyItemChanged(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int)) like so:

```
myList.set(position, newModifiedItem);
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

The item is updated successfully but also are randomly updated some other items, and each time I scroll up and down through my item list, this updates (different icon state) is made on other items too.

I am doing changes in `onBindViewHolder` where I check list item by position and decide to set different status.

**Full Adapter code:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MyObj> myList;

    public MyAdapter(List<MyObj> list) {
        this.myList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MyObj myObj = myList.get(position);
        boolean isSpecial = myObj.getMySpecialStatus();

        holder.myItemTitle.setText(myObj.getTitle());

        //decide if item has different icon state
        if (isSpecial) {
            holder.myItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_special);    
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView myItemTitle;
        public ImageView myItemIcon;
        public LinearLayout itemClickable;
        //some other views

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myItemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            myItemIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_img);

            itemClickable = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_clickable_zone);
            itemClickable.setOnClickListener(this);

            //some other views
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.item_clickable_zone: {

                        //some logic to change status - here just an idea
                        MyObj newModifiedItem = myList.get(position);
                        newModifiedItem.setMySpecialStatus(true);

                        myList.set(position, newModifiedItem);
                        notifyItemChanged(position);
                        break;
                    }

                    //some other views on click
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this happening for title also?

Comment: @Dharmbir Singh no title remains the same

Comment: please post the full adapter code.

Comment: @VasileDoe please show more code

Comment: I posted full code - reduced some irrelevant snippets.

Comment: @MalhotraUrmil there is a part of item that can be pressed, onClick is working fine - the problem is in adapter and its property of reusing views.

Comment: Try to change `... extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GridItemsAdapter.ViewHolder>` with `... extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>`

Comment: @Anggrayudi H I forgot to change it here - this code is simplified for simplicity...

Comment: if you change notifyItemChanged to notifyDataSetChanged - so it'll rebind all views, does it work properly?

Comment: @marmor just tried it - same problem

Comment: i'm guessing your ClickListener gets recycled for some reason, though the code looks ok. try using an anonymous listener ("setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener...") instead of this.
also, you don't need the list.set call, modifying the object will change it in the list as well.

Comment: @marmor I tried it with no success, here on click is not a problem, I logged all super methods, the problem is in RecyclerView property to use same place holder for multiple items, and I don't know how can I handle it

Comment: I have the same problem for sometime with no fix, haven't found too much on this issue, seems like very 10th item in the recycle view gets changed. If I change adapter item position at 0 then item at position 9 gets changed also and then also position 18 and so one ...

Comment: This helped alot ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/47056785/1423608

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your `onBindViewHolder()` where you didn't use `else` case for `if` statement. It shoult be like:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        MyObj myObj = myList.get(position);
        boolean isSpecial = myObj.getMySpecialStatus();

        holder.myItemTitle.setText(myObj.getTitle());

        //decide if item has different icon state
        if (isSpecial) {
            holder.myItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_special);    

         } else {
            //here is the trick - set normal state back
            holder.myItemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_standard);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
MyObj newModifiedItem = myList.get(position); //getting object from the list
newModifiedItem.setMySpecialStatus(true);
notifyItemChanged(position, newModifiedItem);
```

Comment: appreciate your time, but this is exactly the same as I already used with no success

Comment: can you change boolean isSpecial = myObj.getMySpecialStatus(); to final boolean isSpecial = myObj.getMySpecialStatus();