# CheckBox in RecyclerView not working when pressed

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have basic RecyclerView item with TextView and CheckBox. But when I click CheckBox, it does not work. All the more amazing it works when I long pressed.

I made a research and found `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` , `android:clickable="false"`, `android:focusable="false"` , `android:longClickable="false"` but they didn't help me

**Here is my RecyclerView Item layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is my Adapter class**

```
public class FilterTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterTypeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private Context mContext;

    public FilterTypeAdapter() {
    }

    public FilterTypeAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_single_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);

        return vh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mText.setText(mData.get(position));
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Status is: " + isChecked + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // View Holder
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mText;
        private CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            mCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting your onClick, and how?

Comment: Please share code for your onCheckedChangedListener

Comment: Please share your adapter code.

Comment: Added my adapter class

Comment: Try and set the OnCheckedChanged listener in your MyViewHolder class on mCheckBox variable. It is considered bad practice to set click listeners in the onBind call.

Comment: Gil is right: make `MyViewHolder` implement `OnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: Okey. I changed it but still same. Checkbox only work when I long pressed

Comment: [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/rrkRYgHL) works just fine

Comment: Nope, it didn't work

Comment: so what does not work? `OnCheckedChangeListener` is not called or what? how (and where) do you set your listener? is `RecyclerView` inside a normal layout or inside some dialog / popup / float window etc? why do you play with `descendantFocusability`?

Comment: OnCheckedChangeListener is called when only long press to checkbox not a single click, here is the problem

Comment: can you try to remove `android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` from CheckBox tag?

Comment: also remove ` android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

Comment: @RahulKumar still same :(

Comment: why your `textview` has width of 0 dp, can you make it wrap_content and check

Comment: how (and where) do you set your listener? is `RecyclerView` inside a normal layout or inside some dialog / popup / float window etc? why do you play with `descendantFocusability`? and `clickable`? and `focusable`?

Comment: @RahulKumar still same I dont think it's about textview attributes.

Comment: give me a few minutes.. i'll check this out

Comment: my layout works just fine on single click, not on long click

Comment: @pskink RecyclerView inside a normal layout. I made some research and some people have same problem when they have checkbox in list item or rv item so descendantFocusability and clickable works for them but not for me

Comment: so tell me why my layout works just fine?

Comment: @pskink I don't know :) as a point of my view, tell me why my layout does not work

Comment: because of android:focusableInTouchMode android:descendantFocusability android:focusable ? i dont know, just use the simplest form... do not try blindly some random solutions

Comment: So did you checkout the solution i provided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found everything working correctly here.

```
package <your_package>;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import <your_package>.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.test_recyclerview);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i < 1000; i++) {
            data.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new FilterTypeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data));
    }

    public class FilterTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> mData;
    private HashMap<String, Boolean> mChecked;
    private Context mContext;

    public FilterTypeAdapter() {
    }

    public FilterTypeAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
        this.mChecked = new HashMap<>();
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

        View v = TestActivity.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.test_recyclerview_item, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);

        return vh;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mText.setText(mData.get(position));
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        if(mChecked.containsKey(mData.get(position))) {
            holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mChecked.get(mData.get(position)));
        }
        else {
            holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        }
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mChecked.put(mData.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()), isChecked);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Status is: " + isChecked + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
}

    // View Holder
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView mText;
        private AppCompatCheckBox mCheckBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            mCheckBox = (AppCompatCheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);

        }
    }
}
```

R.layout.test_recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

R.layout.testrecyclerview_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: added hashmap for storing which item had checkbox checked.

Comment: I opened a blank project and test your answer. It works as expected. I think something in my project prevent checkbox default behaviour, I need to find this. Thanks your help

Comment: Clean and simple implementation. More straightforward than some other approaches I've seen on SO and blogs. I added a public method for my adapter (contained in a different class) to retrieve the checked hashmap from the calling fragment and everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

remove these lines from checkbox widget

```
 android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

i think this may help