# Android checkbox is not clickable on fragment in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an activity that opens fragment and layout of this is just ViewPager and RecyclerView. On RecyclerView layout element (bottom of attached picture) there is just ImageView and Checkbox.

The problem is when I click on those Checkboxes nothing happens (they stay unclicked).

My fragment looks like this:

[image]

This is how I call this fragment in my Activity:

```
PhotosBrowserFragment browser = PhotosBrowserFragment.newInstance(pics, position, getActivity());
browser.setEnterTransition(new Slide());
browser.setExitTransition(new Slide());
getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addSharedElement(holder.picture, position + "picture")
        .add(R.id.main_layout, browser)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

This is part of recyclerview:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PhotoIndicatorHolder holder, final int position) {

    final PhotoModel pic = pictureList.get(position);

   (...)

    holder.checkBox.setChecked(pic.getSelectedToAdd());
    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PhotoModel photoModel1 = (PhotoModel)holder.checkBox.getTag();
            photoModel1.setSelected(holder.checkBox.isChecked());
            pic.setSelected(holder.checkBox.isChecked());
            notifyItemChanged(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

PhotoModel:

```
public class PhotoModel {

    private String name;
    private String uuid;
    private String path;
    private String size;
    private Boolean selected = false;
    private Boolean selectedToAdd = false;

    public PhotoModel() {
    }

    public PhotoModel(String name, String uuid, String path, String size) {
        this.name = name;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.path = path;
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Boolean getSelectedToAdd() {
        return selectedToAdd;
    }

    public void setSelectedToAdd(Boolean selectedToAdd) {
        this.selectedToAdd = selectedToAdd;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Boolean getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }
```

I can add that I tried a solution from this link: [CheckBox in RecyclerView not working when pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052009/checkbox-in-recyclerview-not-working-when-pressed) but does not work in this case.

If you need more code just ask. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out my recyclerview in layout was placed one before last in Framelayout but if something wants to be clickable needs to be placed as a last one view.